# for loop or lapply (sapply, tapply...?) to extract all counts between two types of variables in a data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, data-structures

I'm using R and I have a dataframe with this kind of structure:

```
age<-c(3,4,3,4,4,5,1)
gender<-c(1,1,2,2,1,3,2)
var1<-c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0)
var2<-c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0)
id<-c(1:7)
df<-data.frame(id, age, gender, var1, var2)
df
  id age gender var1 var2
1  1   3      1    1    0
2  2   4      1    0    0
3  3   3      2    0    1
4  4   4      2    0    1
5  5   4      1    0    1
6  6   5      3    1    0
7  7   1      2    0    0
```

There are two types of variables in the dataframe, demographic questions such as age and gender (about 17 of these, levels varying from 3 to 13), and about 35 "thematic" questions coded 0,1 (1=certain theme present, 0=theme not present). Id is irrelevant here.

I need to wrangle this dataframe into counts of each theme by each level of each demographic question, so the resulting dataframe should be

```
      age1 age3 age4 age5 gender1 gender2 gender3 
var1  0    1    0    1    1       0       1
var2  0    1    2    0    1       2       0
```

I can do this manually (yes, I'm a complete idiot in programming, this is really the best I can do at this point):

```
library(data.table)

t<-table(df$age, df$var1)
dft<-data.frame(t)
dft<-subset(dft, dft$Var1 != 0)
dft<-dft[,2:3]
dft_t<-transpose(dft)
age_var1<-dft_t[2,]
colnames(age_var1)<-c("age1", "age3", "age4", "age5")
rownames(age_var1)<-c("var1")
```

And then the same for gender and var1 = "gender_var1" which I combine into one row by `var1_final<-cbind(age_var1, gender_var1)`

and then the same to var2, resulting in var2_final and then combining all rows with rbind.

Is there any way to do this more fluently? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by leveraging `pivot_longer()` (twice), and then pivoting back to wide format:

```
pivot_longer(pivot_longer(select(df,-id), var1:var2), age:gender,names_to = "type",values_to = "v") %>% 
  mutate(type=paste0(type,v)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = name,names_from = type,values_fn = sum, names_sort=T)
```

Output:

```
  name   age1  age3  age4  age5 gender1 gender2 gender3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 var1      0     1     0     1       1       0       1
2 var2      0     1     2     0       1       2       0
```

Comment: Wow! It works perfectly, thank you so much! It didn't occur to me at all to use pivoting. This saved me SO much time, thank you again!